# joomla error establishing a database connection

Tags: url, redirect, joomla

Working in Joomla, I was trying to update a URL redirect from old URL to new URL via .htaccess but I think in my messing around on the backend, I did something that is now causing old URL to show an error message "**Error establishing a database connection**" and nothing I do is resolving this error message.

Prior to making the change I made a copy of the .htaccess file and renamed it to something else so that if I made a mistake such as this, I could easily revert back to it but restoring that file did not work. I also cleared my cache which fixed other issues but not this particular one. Ended up creating a new page and menu so now the new URL works like it's supposed to. Just trying to learn how to get back the old URL. Please help if someone knows a good fix. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, have you checked the database connexion parameters in configuration.php ? Does the database belong where the old url suppose so?

Comment: Thank you @nicolallias, I forgot to check there and yes, I can already see the problem. Much appreciated!!!